# Saving contents of rich textbox to file, perserving multilines

Tags: c#, .net, savefiledialog

Ok so I'm trying to make a simple text editing program and I got the files to save, but the problem is that all line breaks are removed in the saved file

ie

text as it appears in the text editor

> 123
>   456
>   789

text as it appears in the saved file

> 123456789

code I'm using
`string filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName; File.WriteAllText(filename,richTextBox1.Text);`
and
`string filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

File.AppendAllText(filename, richTextBox1.Text);`

These both produce the same result ie no linebreaks

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to use `File.WriteAllLines` with the `RichTextBox.Lines` property, as `File.WriteAllText` and `File.AppendAllText` is going to ignore you line formatting.

Example

```
string filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
File.WriteAllLines(filename, richTextBox1.Lines);
```

Comment: Worked Thanks, now it makes sense why I couldn't do `File.WriteAllLines(filename, richTextBox1.Text);`

Answer (score 2):

> Try this.

```
 File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog.FileName, richTextBox.Lines);
```